# How do you detect if a sub domain is available using the Azure RM API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net

In the old world (before the Azure RM API), we could detect subdomain availability easily, like so:

```
public async Task<HostedServiceCheckNameAvailabilityResponse> CheckNameAvailability(string name)
{
    using (var client = new ComputeManagementClient(await subscription.GetAuthToken()))
    {
        return await client.HostedServices.CheckNameAvailabilityAsync(name);
    }
}
```

This would tell you if the subdomain was available to use, and it worked great.

In Azure RM, I have not found any similar methods -- I've written the below method as a last resort -- but it's a terrible hack -- and slow to boot; If the sub domain already exists, it only takes about 3 to 4 seconds to tell you that, but if it doesn't exist, it can take up to 25 seconds to run... (creating and deleting the IP takes about 10-12 seconds each) and that really sucks.

```
public static async Task<bool> IsSubDomainAvailable
(
    IAzure azure, 
    string region, 
    string subDomain
)
{
    // TODO: This is a bit of a hack, but it's the only way we've found in the RM
    //       model to test for subdomain availability.

    var rgName = $"dnstest{Guid.NewGuid()}".ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty);
    var resourceGroup = await azure.ResourceGroups.Define(rgName)
        .WithRegion(region)
        .CreateAsync();

    try
    {
        var ipAddy = await azure.PublicIPAddresses.Define("dnstest")
            .WithRegion(region)
            .WithExistingResourceGroup(rgName)
            .WithLeafDomainLabel(subDomain)
            .CreateAsync();

        await azure.PublicIPAddresses.DeleteByIdAsync(ipAddy.Id);

        return true;
    }
    catch (CloudException cEx)
    {
        if (cEx.Response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.BadRequest
            && cEx.Message.ToUpperInvariant().Contains("ALREADY USED"))
        {
            return false;
        }

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        await azure.ResourceGroups.BeginDeleteByNameAsync(rgName);
    }
}
```

**So my question is, is there a better / more direct way to check for sub domain availability, using the Azure RM API?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So my question is, is there a better / more direct way to check for sub domain availability, using the Azure RM API?

We could check for sub domain availability with **NetworkManagementClient** , the following is the demo code.

```
var credentials = SdkContext.AzureCredentialsFactory.FromServicePrincipal(clientId, clientScret,tenantId, AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);

NetworkManagementClient networkManagementClient = new NetworkManagementClient(credentials) {SubscriptionId = subscriptionId};

var result= networkManagementClient.CheckDnsNameAvailabilityWithHttpMessagesAsync("location", "DomainLabelName").Result;
```

Comment: Nice -- I actually ended up using `CheckDnsNameAvailabilityAsync` on the same object, as it has a `bool?` property named `Available`, and I don't have to deal with the `AzureOperationResponse` class / parsing the response. -- But I would have never found it if you hadn't pointed me in the right direction. -- And to boot, the whole thing takes less than a second per call. -- Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Can confirm, there's a lot available in these SDKs but finding what you want is like looking for a needle in a haystack. There's got to be a better way.